# Is given $f$ is uniformly continious ? Yes/No

Tags: real-analysis

Given  $f:(0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ be defined by $$ f(x)=\frac{\log(1 + x^{3})}{x}$$. Now  My question is that  is  $f(x)$  is uniformly continious ?

My attempt : I know that $\log (1+x) \le x$ by  using this  inequality  i get  $f(x) = x^2$   which is  not uniformly contnious  on $( 0, \infty)$

Is its true ?

Comment: You get $f(x) \leq x^2$ but that could be $f(x) = 1 $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument is not valid. The fact that $f(x) \leq x^{2}$ does not tell you that $f$ is not uniformly continuous.

Any continuous function on $(0,\infty)$ which has finite limits at $0$ and $\infty$ is uniformly continuous. 
 In this case show that both limits exist and equal $0$.

For limit at $\infty$ you can use the inequality $\log (1+x^{3})\leq \log (2x^{3})=\log 2+3 log \,  x$ for $x >1$.

Comment: Thanks  u @Kabo....Here limit doesn't exist at  $0$  ..im not getting   ur  approach can  u elaborate more ?

Comment: @jasmine The limit does exist at $0$. Use: $\log (1+x^{3}) \leq x^{3}$

Comment: You also see that by using l'Hospital.

Comment: Yes, we can also use L'Hopital's Rule.